# Mouse delay during drag-select

Tags: 18.04, mouse, ubuntu-mate

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 18.04, and I have a weird issue with drag-selecting icons on my desktop, or within file explorer. When I press my left mouse button and start moving my mouse to select icons (while holding the button), there is a delay between the click and the moment when rectangle for selection starts forming. That results in rectangle forming a centimeter (sometimes two) away from the place I wanted it to form. I've tried several different mice, and the problem still remains.

EDIT:

I just noiced that it happens when I'm drag selecting text as well - the selection starts not on the letter where I clicked, but somewhat later. However, I tend to do that slower than with icons, so I didn't notice the problem earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a long time I was able to find the cause of the problem and the solution for it. The issue was caused by middle mouse button emulation (clicking left and right buttons at the same time). The solution was to disable this using the following command:

```
 gsettings set org.mate.peripherals-mouse middle-button-enabled false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where the selection would start and then "stutter" and restart the selection half way through the drag operation. This meant that I had only half the intended selection which was very annoying.

I thought this was a software problem but after replacing the battery in my wireless mouse the issue went away. Hopefully this helps someone experiencing a similar issue!